# Вывод расписания уроков на указанный день

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решил написать расписание уроков по дням. Основную часть написал, да так коряво написал) На что мозгов хватило так и написал. Крч по коду сможете понять сами  https://pastebin.com/BBfk3vWH

Не дописал, так как там ошибка, которую я не могу решить. Дело в том, что вот в этой части кода

```
if value == 1:
            today +=1
            print(today)
            print("Завтра", today_word, "\n", today_rasp)
            today -=1
```

я хочу чтобы показывало расписание на завтра. Мозги сказали мне приплюсовать единицу и тогда бы оно показывало. Оно то плюсует единицу, но всеравно показывает сегодняшнее число и расписание на сегодня соответственно. Понимаю, код написано коряво, но по другому я не знаю как его написать.

```
#импорт модулей
import sys, datetime

#выяснение текущего дня недели
today = datetime.date.isoweekday(datetime.date.today())

#расписание
monday = """
1. Геометрия
2. Физкультура
3. Немецкий язык
4. Физика
5. Биология
6. Основы здоровье
7. Зарубежная литература
"""

tuesday = """
1. Химия
2. Английский язык
3. Украинский язык
4. Алгебра
5. Украинская литература
6. Информатика
7. Труды
"""

wednesday = """
1. Немецкий язык
2. Мистецтво
3. Алгебра
4. Физика
5. Правознавство
6. География
7. Всемирная история
8. Физкультура
"""

thursday = """
1. Английский язык
2. Алгебра
3. Химия
4. Зарубежная литература
5. Информатика
6. Всемирная история
7. Биология
"""

friday = """
1. Геометрия
2. Физкультура
3. Физика
4. Английский язык
5. Украинский язык
6. География
7. Украинская литература
8. Виховна година
"""
#дни недели
if today == 1:
    today_rasp = monday
    today_word = "понедельник"
if today == 2:
    today_rasp = tuesday
    today_word = "вторник"
if today == 3:
    today_rasp = wednesday
    today_word = "среда"
if today == 4:
    today_rasp = thursday
    today_word = "четверг"
if today == 5:
    today_rasp = friday
    today_word = "пятница"
if today == 6:
    today_word = "суббота"
if today == 7:
    today_word = "воскресенье"

#начало
while True:
    #приветствие
    print("""Расписание уроков 9-Б класа
#### ЗОШ I-III ст. №4""")

    #today
    value = int(input("Сегодня " +today_word+ ".Выдать расписание уроков на сегодня?\n1 - да\n2 - нет\n"))
    if value == 1:
        print(today_rasp)
    if value == 2:
        value = int(input("1 - Выдать расписание уроков на завтра\n2 - Расписание уроков на определённый день\n"))
        if value == 1:
            today +=1
            print(today)
            print("Завтра", today_word, "\n", today_rasp)
            today -=1
        if value == 2:
            value = int(input("1. Понедельник\n"))
```

Comment: Значения переменных today_word и today_rasp не изменены, поэтому и выводится расписание на сегодня, а не на завтра.

Comment: Код нужно включать в вопрос, а не выкладывать на левый сайт.

Comment: @Эникейщик, Если *pastebin* это "левый" сайт, то боюсь узнать кто тут правый..

Comment: @DmytroHoi  Правый тут только один - stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае меняется значения только дня недели, но не инициируется запуск новой проверки какой день, потому не меняется выходное значение.

Дабы не убивать интерес в познании Python поделюсь только направлениями куда копать и тезисами на тему "я бы":

- использовал функцию для проверки, которая получала бы входное значение и проверяла бы соответственно;
- добавил бы вы проверки на первое сообщение и способ выхода из цикла;
- отображал бы выходное значени напрямую из функции, например: `print(timeTable(day))`

Удачи в покорении языка, на будущее стоит учесть специфику и добавлять более техничный вопрос. Вопросы по типу "сделайте за меня" тут не приветствуются.

**UPD: Пример**

к тому куску кода что вверху:

```
# >>> тут инициализировал
def todayInfo(today):
    if today == 1:
        today_rasp = monday
        today_word = "понедельник"
    if today == 2:
        today_rasp = tuesday
        today_word = "вторник"
```

и вызываем где надо:

```
if value == 2:
    value = int(input("1 - Выдать расписание уроков на завтра\n2 - Расписание уроков на определённый день\n"))
    if value == 1:
        todayInfo(today +=1) # вызываем тут <<<
```

Comment: Не понял как написать такую функцию. Сможете написать?

Comment: *добавил в ответ*